# Exponent Upon Exponent?

Tags: logarithms, intuition, puzzle

I can't understand this. Can you please make a clearer explanation?

[image]

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $y=x^{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}}$. Then

$$y = x^{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}} = x^{(x^{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}})} = x^y$$

The book is saying that if $x^{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}}=2$ then we can stick $y=2$ into the above, giving $2=x^2$, and hence $x=\sqrt{2}$. And likewise, if $y=4$ then $4=x^4$, so again $x=\sqrt{2}$.

(In fact, as I'm sure the book goes on to say, the value of $x^{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}}$ when $x=\sqrt{2}$ is in fact $2$ and not $4$.)

Comment: I know that 2=x^y but why is y=2?

Comment: Because $y = x^{x^{x^\ldots}}$, and the equation says $y=2$.

Comment: @user102148: $y$ is the name you give to $x^{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}}$. If you declare that $x^{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}}=2$ then that's exactly the same as saying $y=2$. It's an *assumption* that $y=2$, not something you prove.

Comment: I'm so sorry I don't know how I missed that:( I really need some sleep. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you solve x^x-2=0, the solution is x=1.5596. If you solve x^x^x-2=0, the solution is x=1.4767. If you solve x^x^x^x-2=0, the solution is x=1.4466. If you solve x^x^x^x^x-2=0, the solution is x=1.4327.